# rand with vector of strings in a multimap

Tags: c++, string, vector, multimap

I have a vector of strings and it has three colors. My output only gives me one the first color 'red' where i want it to be random. `vector<string> colors = {"red", "green", "yellow"};` there is something wrong with this code 
`Variety x= static_cast<Variety>(rand()%3);`
    `fruit.insert(make_pair(x,colors[rand()%3]));`
i tried doing +1 but that just makes it green.

```
enum class Variety {
    orange,
    pear,
    apple
};

vector<string> colors = {"red", "green", "yellow"};

struct Fruit {
    Variety v; string color; // red, green or orange
};

int main() {
    multimap<Variety,string> fruit;
    bool foundOrange;
    for (auto j = 0; j < (rand() % 100 + 1); ++j) {
        Variety x = static_cast<Variety>(rand() % 3);
        fruit.insert(make_pair(x, colors[rand() % 3]));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Did you call srand first?

Comment: please provide a [MRE]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All objects made through constructor have the same vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216236/all-objects-made-through-constructor-have-the-same-vectors)

Comment: i actually did not. i didn't know you had to call srand first to use rand?

Comment: Please provide a small example.

Comment: @Dr.-Ing. Gerhard Stein                                                                                 
 ```enum class Variety {orange, pear, apple};```
```vector<string> colors = {"red", "green", "yellow"};```

```struct Fruit{```
  ```Variety v;```
  ```string color; // red, green or orange```
};

```int main(){```
  ```multimap<Variety,string> fruit;```
  ```bool foundOrange;```
  ```for(auto j = 0; j<(rand() %100 +1);++j){```

    ```Variety x= static_cast<Variety>(rand()%3);```
    ```fruit.insert(make_pair(x,colors[rand()%3]));```

Comment: Have you tried with a seed ```srand(time(0)); ```

Comment: @ Dr.-Ing. Gerhard Stein i just tried that and it does a different color but displays the prompt too many times.

Comment: Side note: [rand considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: @ user4581301 so should i user srand() then?

Comment: `rand` and `srand` are a matched set. `srand` is used to set up the initial state (seed) that will be used by subsequent calls to `rand`. The problem with `rand` is it's a 1970's solution that deals with 1970s problems  like hardware measured in Hz and bytes rather than gigaHz and gigabytes. It take shortcuts that Mr. Lavavej pokes great fun at in his presentation. It can barely be considered random under some circumstances. Modern C++'s [`<random>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) is discussed at length in the presentation. Prefer to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The right way of using `rand()` is to call `srand()` first. `srand()` will generate a series of random numbers, and `rand()` will simply iterate over them. If you don't call `srand()` you will get the same number every time you'll use 'rand()`.

`srand` example:

```
int main() {
    // Call this function once to generate the random numbers using the seed `time(NULL)`
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << rand() % 5 << std::endl; // Go through the random numbers series
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, in C++ there is the `<random>` library, that will make your life way more easier in the task of generate random numbers (and will work really better then using `srand` & `rand`).

```
// Function to generate random numbers between `min` and `max` params
size_t get_random(size_t min, size_t max) {
    // the generator will only be seeded once since it's static (Equivalent to calling `srand` once)
    static std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(min, max);
    return dist(gen); // generate random number
}
```

Credit for function idea: @[TedLyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo).
See more delails: [All objects made through constructor have the same vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216236/all-objects-made-through-constructor-have-the-same-vectors)

Comment: thank you that fixed it! i didnt call srand() before the use of rand()

Comment: @Keegs no problem, but pay attention that `srand` & `rand` may not always work, and there are more recommended ways for generating random numbers in C++.