# Proper way to generate random long long?

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate random `long long` numbers using this code in C++:

```
random_device rd;
default_random_engine gen(rd());

uniform_int_distribution<long long> distribution(1, llround(pow(10, 12)));
long long random_num = distribution(gen);
```

I just want to verify that this should generate random integers from [1, 10^12] uniformly. Is this the correct way to do it?

EDIT:

```
random_device rd;
mt19937_64 gen(rd());

uniform_int_distribution<long long> distribution(1, llround(pow(10, 12)));
long long random_num = distribution(gen);
```

Comment: Instead of `default_random_engine`, I'd use `std::mt19937`. So you know you're getting high-quality random numbers.

Comment: I'd replace the call to `pow` with a compile time constant, but that shouldn't hurt you. Also keep an eye out for the [deliberately broken `random_device`  implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device#Notes) in older versions of mingw.

Comment: @user4581301 Do you happen to know why it was deliberately broken?

Comment: @Ayxan It seems `std::mt19937` is for generating 32 bit numbers. Can I still use this to generate up to 10^12?

Comment: @Ayxan Probably more reasons than I'm aware of, but a big one being the lack of a good, trustworthy, and not-licence-encumbered RNG. They made it obviously broken rather than toss in a half-assed fix that looked like it worked and resulted in vulnerable applications.

Comment: @bayesianpower [There is also mt19937_64](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)

Comment: Don't use `pow` instead either implement your own function or make it a literal. `pow` sometimes gives a wrong answer due to float point precision. Look here for example: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/1521

Comment: @bayesianpower — `std::uniform_int_distribution` knows how to manage RNGs whose output range is smaller then the target range.

Comment: "Can I still use this" - yes. If `uniform_int_distribution` needs more randoms bits than a single call to `mt19937` can give, it will make multiple calls. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/NiQdR5)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've edited the post to `mt19937_64`, which I guess provides higher quality random numbers. Is this satisfiable now?

Also @MahmoodDarwish I thought the wrong answer was due to int casting dropping the remainders, which I'm not doing here so I think it is okay?

Comment: Mixing integral and floating point numbers for no good reason is a dangerous thing. Not every integer can be represented exactly, and you might get unexpected errors. For example, `std::llround(std::pow(9, 17))` gives `16677181699666568`, whereas the `9^17 = 16677181699666569`.

Comment: Note that you are only seeding the generator / engine with a single integer. That may or may not be ok for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Combining all the comments above,

1. Prefer `std::mt19937` or `std::mt19937_64` to `std::default_random_engine` to get high-quality random numbers. You can use both generators with `std::uniform_int_distribution`. Distributions know how to manage generators whose output range is smaller then the target range.
2. Instead of `std::llround(std::pow(10, 12))` prefer the compile-time constant (`1'000'000'000'000LL`). In general, not every integer can be represented exactly, and you might get unexpected results. For example, `std::llround(std::pow(9, 17))` gives `16677181699666568`, whereas the `9^17 = 16677181699666569`.
3. Seeding a generator with a single number (typically, 32-bit), `std::mt19937_64 gen(rd())`, is the simplest thing you can do. In some situations you might want to use more bits of entropy, i.e. not just a single number, but a seed sequence. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45069219) for more details.