# Why Does C++ Map Say That Struct Exists When Doesn't?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a struct called foo, and also a map called mp, but for some reason, when I insert {5, 0, 3} and query for {5, 3, 0}, the map says that it contains {5, 3, 0} when it actually doesn't:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int v1, v2, v3;
    friend bool operator<(const foo &a, const foo &b) {
        return a.v1 < b.v1;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const foo &a, const foo &b) {
        return (a.v1 == b.v1) && (a.v2 == b.v2) && (a.v3 == b.v3);
    }
};

int main() {    
    map<foo, int> mp;
    mp[{5, 0, 3}] = 1;
    if(mp[{5, 3, 0}]) {
        cout << "YES\n";
    } else {
        cout << "NO\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
YES
```

Does anyone know why my code is doing this? If so, what do I need to change?

Comment: Unrelated: You can seed the PRNG better with `mt19937_64 rng(std::random_device{}());`

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Assuming `std::random_device` isn't a fake. And also, it's still only seeding with an `unsigned int`'s worth of a randomness. [It's deeply terrible how hard it is to seed the C++ PRNGs properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45069219/364696).

Comment: If the key can't be found in the map [] adds the key to the map.

Comment: I know, but the default value is 0, and not 1...

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Also note that all those global type-aliases and the global variables are a really bad habit as well. You should never use such things in "real" code that you give to teachers, interviews or at jobs in general.

Comment: Bruh, I know, but this isn't for job interview, you're suggesting the wrong stuff to the wrong people. I do things like USACO where bits/stdc++.h is useful. Please just tell me what's wrong with my map and not stuff that isn't helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowRanger True, but it's very rarely fake nowadays - and an `unsigned` is usually good enough for small programs. Otherwise one could make a `seed_seq` to fill the MT's gigantic state :-)

Comment: We don't know your background. For all we know, you could be using bad sites to actually try to learn the basics or programming, which are not their purpose. It seems all example on such sites are just awful, and should only be used as bad examples. And habits tend to stick, especially bad ones. Better use good habits and write nice, good and clean code to begin with. Even for so-called "competitions".

Comment: @JaMiT, sorry, what I said wasn't quite clear. What I meant was that if you look at the debug output, the map returns true for the state {5, 3, 0} when we haven't even processed it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to edit it quickly. :)

Comment: `mp[{5, 3, 0}]` ***adds*** the structure to the map.

Comment: It's called a template. And before you even provide more feedback, the "nonstandard tree class" is known as an ordered set

Comment: I know it adds the structure to the map, but why would it return true? Isn't the default value of adding a new structure 0?

Comment: Why is it if I default add an int, it default sets to 0?

Comment: `operator<` only checks `v1`so `5,0,3` and `5,3,0` are equivalent. `operator==` is never used.

Comment: Alr thanks! I'll drop the cin.tie thing and if you post a solution, I'll gladly mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Unrelated: @Ted Lyngmo: There is a case for the seed used in the OP, because it has 64 bits, while a single call to `std::random_device` returns only 32. That is why I prefer something like this (provided that `std::random_device` is a reliable source of entropy): `std::random_device rd; std::uint64_t seed1{ rd() }, seed2{ rd() }; std::mt19937_64 rng(seed1 << 32u | seed2);`. Far superior to both would be to use a seeding library that seeds all 19,968 bits of state, such as [this one](https://github.com/tbxfreeware/seed_randomly).

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding somewhere here... You can't use `mp[{5, 3, 0}]` to check for existence of an element in a map. Even if the default data value is zero, that will insert the element into the map so the check you have to see if the element exist effectively creates that element. So after your check, the element will exist in the map, even if you "fix" the flawed comparison operator. Use either `find`, `count` or `contains` to check for map element existence.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yep, changing my operator< seems to have solve the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Your `operator <` should be: `return std::tie(a.v1, a.v2, a.v3) < std::tie (b.v1, b.v2, b.v3);`

Comment: @tbxfreeware If I want a better seed, I usually use `seed_seq`. It doesn't have to be more complicated than: `auto seed = []<std::size_t... R>(std::index_sequence<R...>) { std::random_device rd; return std::seed_seq{((void)R, rd())...};}(std::make_index_sequence<16>());`

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo: I am impressed! That is a pretty fancy way to construct a seed sequence from 16 calls to `std::random_device`. I admit it! It's above my pay grade.

Comment: @tbxfreeware :) One could always fill a `vector` and use the `seed_seq` constructor taking iterators too.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo You have given me a reason to finally add fold expressions to my repertoire! I am also happy with the seeding library I linked. It uses class `seed_seq_rd`, which creates a faux seed sequence object with a footprint of only 4 bytes. The `generate` function of `seed_seq_rd` calls `random_device` to fill the target range, and makes no attempt to scramble the results. For `mt19937`, it calls `random_device` 624 times, once for each state variable. So long as `random_device` is doing its job, any of the possible states might result, which is not the case with a regular `seed_seq`.

Comment: @tbxfreeware Glad it served as some inspiration! Using a "faked" `seed_seq` that actually returns the `random_device` values directly sounds like a great solution, so be happy with it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison operator does not match your equality operator. A `std::map` does not use the equality operator; it uses "less than". If neither `a < b` nor `b < a` then the map considers `a` and `b` equivalent. In your case:

- `foo{5, 0, 3} < foo{5, 3, 0}` is `false` because `5 < 5` is false.
- `foo{5, 3, 0} < foo{5, 0, 3}` is `false` because `5 < 5` is false.

So the map considers these objects equivalent. So `mp[{5, 3, 0}]` finds the map element you just set to 1, hence it is a true value.

To get the result you want, your `operator<` needs to account for all three members, not just `v1`.

For example:

```cpp
    friend bool operator<(const foo &a, const foo &b) {
        if (a.v1 != b.v1)
            return a.v1 < b.v1;
        if (a.v2 != b.v2)
            return a.v2 < b.v2;
        return a.v3 < b.v3;
    }
```

or (as PaulMcKenzie suggested) more simply:

```
    friend bool operator<(const foo &a, const foo &b) {
        return std::tie(a.v1, a.v2, a.v3) < std::tie (b.v1, b.v2, b.v3);
    }
```

Comment: How would I make it so that accounts for all three members? Since I just tried this which at least returns the right answer but still has some sort of issue that leads to a TLE: 
    struct foo {
        int v1, v2, v3;
        friend bool operator<(const foo &a, const foo &b) {
            if(a.v1 < b.v1) {
                return true;
            } else if(a.v2 < b.v2) {
                return true;
            } else if(a.v3 < b.v3) {
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    };

Comment: @zrli -- See my comment in the main comment section.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok

Comment: @zrli `if(a.v1 < b.v1) { return true; } else if(a.v2 < b.v2) { return true; } else if(a.v3 < b.v3) { return true; } return false;` -- The error here occurs when `a.v1 > b.v1` and the other fields have values that cause your operator to return `true`. Using `std:tie` (as 
PaulMcKenzie suggested) allows you to not have to remember all the ways this comparison function can go wrong (and that others have run into hundreds of times).

Comment: @JaMiT yep, that issue is solved now! Would you by chance to know whether a struct is more time costly than a tuple?

Comment: @JaMiT You have to check v2 only if v1 is equal. And v3 only if v2 and v1 is equal.

Comment: @zrli There is no inherent performance difference between a `class` (such as `std::tuple`) and a `struct` (such as `foo`).

Comment: @MarcusHampel Yes, I know that. Are you saying I should add more details to my answer?

Comment: @JaMiT I was just wondering if I needed to change my idea or my struct since I get TLE when trying to solve the coding problem in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

```
int v1, v2, v3;
friend bool operator<(const foo &a, const foo &b) {
    return a.v1 < b.v1;
}
```

firstly, this only checks the first value. So 5,0,0 will be considered the same a 5,9,9, etc.

```
   if(mp[{5, 3, 0}])
```

This doesn't work the way you think. Operator[] will create a new entry if one doesn't exist. However as it is inserting a value of 0, your if statement is giving the result you expect, but it is not doing it in the way you expect. This kind of "side effect" is bad, this is where bugs creep in. You shoudl use methods like map.find() instead